# The value '' is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET application to create distribution lists. It works fine on my development machine using IIS Express, but on the server, I am getting the following error from the standard output:

> The value '' is invalid.

Below is the code I am using to mail-enable the distribution list. I have replaced the powershell script with a simple "echo test" batch file, but the same error still comes from the standard output.

```
//ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("c:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", "c:\\PowershellScripts\\EnableDL.ps1 -dlName '" + model.Name + "'");
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("c:\\powershellscripts\\test.bat");
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.Domain = "CONTOSO.COM";
info.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
info.Password = securePassword;

using (Process run = Process.Start(info))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("dlcreate", run.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    run.WaitForExit();
}
```

I just don't understand what could be causing this. Running the script on my dev machine (IIS Express) works fine, and running the script as the user on the server via CMD also works fine. I can't even reproduce the error via CMD. Any ideas?

UPDATE: Not sure if it is of any help, but when I remove the Domain, Username, and Password objects, all executables run without issue under the DefaultAppPool user.

Comment: It is most probably related with Security.

Comment: I believe so, but the ASP.NET pool is already running at full trust on the IIS + Site + Application level. I'm not sure what other security settings could possibly be blocking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that are getting this problem. I have found the issue to be that the user which you are impersonating does not have permissions to run the application within the desktop of the IIS service.

The sample code linked at the bottom of [This Page](http://asprosys.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/perils-and-pitfalls-of-launching.html) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need "Full trust" on your ASP.Net app to launch something in the shell. Here is a link talking about trust levels on Web Applications.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/330a99hc(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: The server and application are already set to Full Trust in the IIS Manager. Is there another setting which may be blocking it?